# What is an environment, really?

Tags: environments

I consider myself a moderately proficient LaTeX user. Occasionally, I want to do something that is similar enough to an implementation found in a package that duplicating it seems pointless, but distinct enough that the package options do not necessarily allow me to easily achieve it. Under these circumstances, I often end up creating a local implementation of some `\Package@PrivateCommand` that is subtly modified, and using it in my document(s).

However, I have frequently found that packages which provide environments have a richer structure than those which do not. I know that one can readily define a new environment with LaTeX (i.e. that the `\newenvironment` command exists), but for some reason, packages which provide environments don't seem to do this directly. For example, the `multicols` package doesn't feature a single `\newenvironment` in [its source](http://math.bard.edu/bloch/multicol.sty) at all -- instead, it's a complex mixture of things like `\def\prepare@multicols` and various macros that appear to be run before an environment, as well as after it. As one would expect, this makes changing things a lot more interesting for an ignorant person like me :-).

Correspondingly, I strongly suspect that ``` \begin{environment}{Argument} ``Some content goes here'' \end{environment} ``` is just syntactic sugar for something like what the TeX equivalent would be, namely:

```
\EnvironmentPreHook
\argumentMacro{Argument}
``Some content goes here''
\EnvironmentPostHook
```

Am I correct? How are environments parsed? Are there any circumstances where this can cause real problems? Is this related to, for example, why `\centering` can do the same job (in a given scope) as `begin{center} ... \end{center}`?

I've had a quick look through the documentation I can find, and a detailed explanation (ideally along the lines of [What is a macro, really?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263978/what-is-a-macro-really)) is missing.

Comment: Hello! Would this help you? [_How does LaTeX implement environments?_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58269/11002) To me it seems that your question asks more or less the same thing.